# How to write labels horizontally on y-axis with axis()

Tags: r, bar-chart

**Purpose**

Write labels horizontal with `axis()` after `barplot()`.

**Code**

```
par(mai=c(2, 1, 1, 1), lwd=2)
barplot(as.numeric(c(2, 4, 1, 6)), col = c("lightblue"), main="Bar plot",
        names.arg=c("This is bar 1...1","This is bar 1...2",
                    "This is bar 1...3","This is bar 1...4"),
        xpd=TRUE, las=2, lwd=2, axes=FALSE, axis.lty=1,
        cex.axis=1, cex.names=1, cex.main=1, ylim=c(-5,8.5),xlim=c(-6,5))
axis(2, -3:9)
```

**See on picture**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were nearly there! You'd set las for the x axis, but not the y (which was called separately). Here:

```
par(mai=c(2, 1, 1, 1), lwd=2)
barplot(as.numeric(c(2, 4, 1, 6)), col = c("lightblue"), main="Bar plot",
        names.arg=c("This is bar 1...1","This is bar 1...2",
                    "This is bar 1...3","This is bar 1...4"),
        xpd=TRUE, las=2, lwd=2, axes=FALSE, axis.lty=1,
        cex.axis=1, cex.names=1, cex.main=1, ylim=c(-5, 8.5), xlim=c(-6, 5))
axis(2, -3:9, las=2)
```